# Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'config' of undefined]

Tags: lightning-aura-components

**below is code spinner**

**calling below controller method from my compoent**

```
<lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:refresh"  disabled="false" alternativeText="Resfresh (disabled)" title="Refresh (disabled)" onclick="{! c.doInit}"/>
```

Controller method:

```
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.doInitHelper(component, event, helper);
    }
```

helper method:

```
doInitHelper: function (component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.newInboundContact', {INS_ContactMethod__c:'Phone', INS_BusinessStream__c:'', INS_Category__c:'', INS_Reason__c:''});
        component.set('v.caseID', '');
        component.set('v.isDisabled', false);
        
        var contactRecordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var checkIfForC360 = component.get("v.forcustomer360");
        if(checkIfForC360){
            var inputParam = {
                'contactID': contactRecordId
          };
          helper.callServer(component, "c.fetchINS_Occupant",
                          function(response){
                              // component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class", 'slds-hide');
                              var result = JSON.parse(response);
                              if(!result.hasError){
                              var resultList = [];
                              if (result.occupantSearchResultList.length === 0) {
                                      component.set("v.results", resultList);
                                      component.set("v.message", true);
                                      component.set("v.hasContact", true);
                                      //component.set("v.conditionCheck", false);
                                      //component.set("v.isShowSearchResult", true);
                                  }else {
                                      resultList = result.occupantSearchResultList;
                                      component.set("v.results", resultList);
                                      //component.set("v.isShowSearchResult", true);
                                      component.set("v.Message", false);
                                      component.set("v.hasContact", true);
                                      //component.set("v.conditionCheck", false);
                                      //component.set("v.locationID", '');
                                      //component.set("v.contactID", '');
                                      //component.set("v.showSearchForm", false);
                                      //component.set("v.showSearchForm", true);
                                  }
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              'searchInputParameters': JSON.stringify(inputParam)
                          }
                         );
        }
        
    }
**callServer method:**
 callServer: function (component, method, callback, params) {
        var action = component.get(method);
        if (params) {
            action.setParams(params);
        }
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('@@@@STATE@@'+state);
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                callback.call(this, response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Oops!",
                    "message": "No Internet Connection",
                    "type": 'info'
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                        toastEvent.setParams({
                            "title": "Error!",
                            "message": "Please contact your administrator",
                            "type": 'error'
                        });
                        toastEvent.fire();
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

above code is working fine at the time of page load. and also working fine from the button icon if there is no data at time of page load. if there is data a at time of page load then on click if icon button the below error is throwing.

> ```
> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'config' of undefined]
> Callback failed: apex://INS_ManageLocationsController/ACTION$fetchINS_Occupant
> ```

Comment: Can you share the full code?